# Upload file using formData (axios -> php)

Tags: javascript, php, multipartform-data, axios

I am trying to send `.csv` file using `axios` (`formData`) and I am getting always empty array in controller.

Here is my code and what I have try to do.

HTML

```
<input id="upload-csv-<?= $fraction->id ?>" name="uploadcsv"
 onChange="return uploadCsv(<?= $fraction->id ?>)"
 type="file" required="required"/ >
```

JS

```
function uploadCsv(fractionId) {
  let groupId = $('#customer_id').val();
  let selectedFile = $('#upload-csv-' + fractionId)[0] ? $('#upload-csv-' + fractionId)[0].files : undefined;
  const data = new FormData();
  data.append('group_id', groupId);
  data.append('fraction_id', fractionId);
  data.append('file', selectedFile);
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    return axios.post('/refunds/uploadRefundCsv', data)
    .then(function(response) {
  ....
```

In controller i am making `debug($_FILES)` and array is empty `[]`

I have also tried with examples described in [Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects)

Only way to get var `$_FILES` not empty is

```
let file = new Blob([selectedFile ], { type: "text/xml"});
```

but then I can not read my file (my file is somehow overwriten and I am getting only message `[object FileList]` )

Comment: What is the value of $_POST ?

Comment: group_id and fraction_id are in, but file is empty, only if I am using new Blob, but that convert my file to something other -> [object FileList]

Comment: Have you tried to console.log(data) before `return Promise...`?

Comment: I have found a problem. selectedFile is array and I have to get first element selectedFile[0]. But however thank you for helping